# Can zmq.asyncio.ZMQEventLoop be used like a normal asyncio event loop?

Tags: zeromq, python-asyncio, pyzmq

I am trying to forward data between a ZMQ socket and a websocket. The [websockets](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets) library is normally used like this:

```
start_server = websockets.serve(handler, 'localhost', 8000)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
```

Now, ZMQ seems to require [its own event loop](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/blob/master/zmq/asyncio.py):

```
loop = zmq.asyncio.ZMQEventLoop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
start_server = websockets.serve(handler, 'localhost', 8000);
loop.run_until_complete(start_server)
```

But I'm getting errors like this:

```
[...]
  File "[...]/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/zmq/asyncio.py", line 71, in register
    raise ValueError("Invalid events: %r" % events)
ValueError: Invalid events: 3
```

Can ZMQEventLoop be used like this at all?

(Apologies for my sketchy knowledge of asyncio)

**UPDATE**

Turns out this was [a bug in pyzmq](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/issues/775). Updating to version 15.2.0 fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks for updating your own question and posting the answer.